# Not get logged in chrome.302 status came

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, customer-session

I am not able to login in `Chrome` but able to login `Firefox`,`Internet Explorer`.I have added session time `24hrs` from admin settings.Also tried with core `varient.php` file  session code commented, but no any success.And I have checked in network,it show login `ajax status 302` , temporary moved. But same is working in `Firefox` without any issue.